# ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialised <controller name>)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controller

I've checked for the usual spelling mistakes or files in the wrong place.  Undoubtedly it will be something simple - but I just can't see it.  What am I missing?

controllers/admin/top_10_pages_controller.rb

```
class Admin::Top10PagesController < Admin::AdminController

end
```

models/top_10_page.rb

```
class Top10Page < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :top_10_pages
end
```

rake routes

```
admin_top_10_pages     GET    /admin/top_10_pages           admin/top_10_pages#index                      
                       POST   /admin/top_10_pages           admin/top_10_pages#create                            
new_admin_top_10_page  GET    /admin/top_10_pages/new       admin/top_10_pages#new                      
edit_admin_top_10_page GET    /admin/top_10_pages/:id/edit  admin/top_10_pages#edit                     
admin_top_10_page      GET    /admin/top_10_pages/:id       admin/top_10_pages#show                   
                       PUT    /admin/top_10_pages/:id       admin/top_10_pages#update                 
                       DELETE /admin/top_10_pages/:id       admin/top_10_pages#destroy
```

URL Called

```
/admin/top_10_pages
```

ERROR from development log

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Admin::Top10PagesController):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bob - I think this is an issue with the name of the controller file itself.

When I run `"Top10PagesController".underscore` in the console I get `"top10_pages_controller"` rather than `"top_10_pages_controller"`

Looks like rails is looking for the wrong controller file. Try changing the controller name to top10_pages_controller.rb and see if that works?

Comment: Many thanks for this. Changed the filename as suggested, also the view folder name, and all works great.  It's interesting that 'rails g controller Top10Pages' generated the file top_10_pages_controller! - Thanks again for the help :-)